# Nami shows all minted NFTs in "Assets" tab instead of "Collectibles" tab

Tags: nft, minting, metadata, python, nami

the following image illustrates my problem: all the NFTs I've been minting is being seen as normal native tokens instead of collectibles.

For example, for the ANIMALSP01#28, the metadata in the transaction is:

```
{
721:{
   58acb2cb1ae017ede95e8e0a5801e0b3fc3036296adc242490d53cfd: {
      414e494d414c53503031233238: {
         description: "",
         name: "Koala",
         type: "Animal",
         image: "ipfs://QmcYZXh9mjdNC1TfyPKWSbGF2LV5Y7Et75A5DwjjRktMUH",
         Race: "Koala"
      }
   }
}
}
```

And I am generating this way:

```
policy = ScriptAll([pub_key_policy, must_before_slot])
policy_id = policy.hash()

NFT_NAME = nft_name.encode("utf8")
metadata = {
            721: {  # 721 refers to the metadata label registered for NFT standard here:
                # https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0010/registry.json#L14-L17
                policy_id.payload.hex(): {
                    NFT_NAME: {
                        "description": description,
                        "name": name,
                        "type": type,
                        "image":"ipfs://" + nft.file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope someone can help me :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset name in the metadata should probably be "ANIMALSP01#28" instead of the hex representation ("414e494d414c53503031233238"), according to the version 1 of [CIP-025](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0025).

Comment: you are completely right. I was wrong because of the example given in the pycardano's repository